# How to assign data to next page in PHP

Tags: php

In smarty we can assign data like this:

```
$smarty->assign("key",$value);
```

Then we can use this value in tpl file and the value can be anything(int,string,array,etc.)

How can we get this way with PHP only?
Can anyone explain me?

Comment: There is not enough information to tell you exactly what you need but you could take  a look at sessions or (hidden) form fields to get information from one page to another.

Comment: If so, can session carry all type and large amount of data (for example, all users post and comments)?

Comment: Com'on, do your homework, google it, try some code. If it doesn't work, share your code on stackoverflow to get some help.